# How to enter variable to a urll in batch file

Tags: variables, batch-file, echo

I have a text file look like:

```
Hello
World
How
Are
You
```

I have a for loop that set only that last line to a var:

```
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (file.txt) do (
set var_test=%%a
)
```

When I echo `%var_test%` it prints me the whole file

When I echo `!var_test!` it prints only the last line

Now I'm trying to echo the last line to a url: `www.mysite.com/You&123`

So I'm doing `echo www.mysite.com/%var_test%&123` and get the whole file in the url

If I'm doing `echo www.mysite.com/!var_test!&123` I get `www.mysite.com/!var_test!&123` and not the content of the var

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me on Windows:

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (file.txt) do (
    set var_test=%%a
    echo www.mysite.com/^!var_test^!^&123
)
```

Note the `^` before the `!` and `&` to ensure that those do get interpreted as commands.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't work. it prints me var_test instead of the content. but I tried something else, Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
setLocal
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (file.txt) do (
set var_test=%%a
)
echo www.mysite.com/%var_test%^&123
```

should `echo` the string

```
www.mysite.com/You&123
```

If that's what you want. Sadly, you don't show us what you are "doing" in-context, nor what you actually want as output.

Comment: Thanks. I want the string www.mysite.com/You&123, but I didn't get it. I got www.mysite.com/Hello World How Are You&123. but I tried to do something else. thanks anyway